# groupby().transform(): Length of values does not match length of index

Tags: python, pandas

I want to serialize all rows having the same values of `room`, `box_num` and the first `begintime`. I tried to use `df.groupby().transform()`:

```
df['group_num'] = pd.factorize(df['room'].astype(str) + df['box_num'].astype(str) + \
    df.groupby('hash')['begintime'].transform(min).astype(str))
```

But I get the error:

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

As I know, `transform` returns `Series` with unchanged size. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing last `[0]` for select first array, because [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) return 2 arrays:

```
df['group_num'] = pd.factorize(df['room'].astype(str) + df['box_num'].astype(str) + \
df.groupby('hash')['begintime'].transform(min).astype(str))[0]
```

Comment: @anky_91 - I hope it is reason for this